# Error html user tag canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a source code. I use tag canvas in code HTML. I have one tag div before 11 tag Canvas and two tag div behind tag canvas. When I run the code the error occurred.

If I set property of height for `canvas < 50px` then arrow hidden.
And if I don't set property of heigth of canvas. When I run the code, the display: tag div `MISSSSS` and `MOMMMMM` between tag canvas. Sorry I don't post image display because I do not has the right.

I want to `MISSSSSS` and `MOMMMMMM` behind canvas.
And I want set property of height for `canvas = 30px` don't hidden arrow.

[Live example on the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j7vx5dz/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>LOLLL</div>
<div style="height:30px;">
    <canvas id="text_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="text_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_2" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="text_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_2" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="text_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_2" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="text_1" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_2" width="120" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="arrow_2" width="120" ></canvas>
</div>
<div>MISSSSSS</div>
<div>MOMMMM</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
    var t = setTimeout("resize()", 200);
else
    resize();

function resize() {
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var targetWidth = 800;
    var targetHeight = 600;
    window.resizeBy(targetWidth-innerWidth, targetHeight-innerHeight);
}

function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 20;   // length of head in pixels
    var dx = tox-fromx;
    var dy = toy-fromy;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineWidth=2;
    //context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    var count= parseInt($("canvas").length);
    for(var i=0; i< count; i++){
        var ctx= $("canvas")[i].getContext('2d');
        var temp= $("canvas")[i].id;
        if(temp.indexOf("text") != -1){
                ctx.font="15px Times New Roman";
                ctx.fillText("I Love My Mom",10,10);
            }           
        else{
            if(temp.indexOf("arrow") != -1){
                ctx.beginPath();
                canvas_arrow(ctx,10,10,100,10);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about what your goal is, but try `overflow:hidden;` in addition to `height: 30px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/9j7vx5dz/2/

Comment: Thank you for support. But i have 13 canvas but when i run source code , 4 tag canvas hidden. I want display 13 tag canvas then 2 tag div. Help me!

Comment: Then remove height:30px;, but keep overflow:hidden;